# how same pointer get different values in c?

Tags: c

I write this code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int tst;
    tst = 23;
    char buf[0];
    int * k = &tst;
    printf("%p.. %d\n", k, *k);
    sprintf(buf, "%p", &tst);
    intptr_t x = buf;
    int* y = x;
    printf("%p...%d", y, *y);
    return 0;
}
```

and its output:

```
0028FF34.. 23
0028FF34...942813232
```

so with same pointer I have different value!
what I must do for get same value?

Edit: I change code:

```
int main() {
int tst;
tst = 23;
char buf[4];
int * k = &tst;
printf("%p.. %d\n", k, *k);
sprintf(buf, "%p", &tst);
void* i;
sscanf(buf,"%p",&i);

int* o = i;
printf("i: %p %d\n",i, *o);
intptr_t x = buf;
int* y = x;
printf("%p...%d\n", y, *y);
return 0;
}
```

it work [here](https://ideone.com/B7yyuB) but in my computer it has problem!

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the use of the parameters in this line:  `sprintf(buf, "%p", &tst);`

Comment: running it [here](https://ideone.com/SPJgDL) gives different pointer values

Comment: `char buf[0];` defines an array capable of holding zero elements. You can't `sprintf()` into that array.

Comment: The `sprintf()` will most likely segfault because it's trying to write to a `buf`, which is declared as zero-length. Equally, the 2nd `printf()` tries to dereference `y` as an `int` (say 4 bytes), which equals `x`, which equals `buf`, so that will likely segfault too.

Comment: @yate: what I must do now!? :(

Answer (score 0):

K contains the Address of tst `int * k = &tst;`by printing K you are printer address of tst. and by dereferencing K you are printing value of tst because K contains address of tst.

Comment: I have question about "y"! why *y != *k?!

Comment: `y` is the address of `buf`, not `k`

Answer (score -1):

I solve this problem like this:

```
int main() {
int tst;
tst = 23;
char* buf=malloc(sizeof(void*)); //here!!! :D
int * k = &tst;
printf("%p.. %d\n", k, *k);
sprintf(buf, "%p", &tst);
void* i;
sscanf(buf,"%p",&i);

int* o = i;
printf("i: %p %d\n",i, *o);
intptr_t x = buf;
int* y = x;
printf("%p...%d\n", y, *y);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `buf` is still too small - you allocate 4 bytes and write 9 (on a 32-bit system).